# Need help getting value Google Maps API .pac-container class

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

on user click, I'm trying to extract the value out of the ".pac-item" class when a user types in a location using the google maps api.

I've read the following

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete.

Since the `.pac-container` class is generated dynamically, I've tried the using an event handler to listen on `.pac-container` class, but cannot get the name or place of the user click to console.log or event log anything.

```
$(document).on("click", ".pac-container", function(event) {

  var selected = $(this).val().trim();

  console.log(event);

  console.log("selected: " + selected);

});

I've also tried

$(document).on("click", ".pac-item", function(event) {

  var selected = $(this).val().trim();

  console.log(event);

  console.log("selected: " + selected);

});
```

I'm expecting on user click, the value of whatever place was clicked. For example, if user types portland and the `.pac-container` items list:

portland, or, us
portland international airport station
portland international airport

if the user clicks on portland, or, us I want that string saved into my selected variable.

right now, nothing is will console.log and no event are console.log as well.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, sort of figured out a solution to this.

In this part of the google maps code:

```
searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function () {

    var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

    googleLng = searchBox.bounds.ga.j;

    //give the lng some precision, as the open weather map api doesn't like 
    floating point numbers too long
    googleLng = googleLng.toPrecision(5);

    googleLat = searchBox.bounds.ma.j;

    //give the lat some precision, as the open weather map api doesn't like 
    floating point numbers too long
    googleLat = googleLat.toPrecision(5);

    console.log(googleLng);
    console.log(googleLat);

    clicktoCoord(googleLat, googleLng);


    if (places.length == 0) {
        return;
    }

    // Clear out the old markers.
    markers.forEach(function (marker) {
    marker.setMap(null);
    });
```

console.log(searchBox) returned an object which contained data I needed within it (lattitude and longitude) on the ".pac-item" list. With the latitude and longtitude, I was able to just throw this into an open weather map ajax api call and am able to get weather conditions on whatever "pac-item" list the user clicked on.

Hopefully this helps someone.